# Bootstrap Table Scroll Bar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and have a list of columns inside a table. The table column so long and I would like to make it that there is a scrollbar of the table that displays elements having to scroll side.

Here is my code below:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>PIN Number</th>
    <th>Full Name</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Organization</th>
    <th>Branch Code</th>
    <th>Campus</th>
    <th>Leave Type</th>
    <th>Date From</th>
    <th>Date To</th>
    <th>Days</th>
    <th>Reason</th>
    <th>Responsible PIN</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: horizontal or verical scroll you wants

Comment: horizontal scroll @Anubhav

Answer (score 0):

Just add div tag with overflow auto css like following code :-

```
<div style="overflow: auto;">
    <table class="table">....</table>
</div>
```

or you can add table-responsive class to that div like following :-

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">....</table>
</div>
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, hope it helps.

```css
.table-wrapper {
  max-width: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="table-wrapper">

  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>PIN Number</th>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Organization</th>
      <th>Branch Code</th>
      <th>Campus</th>
      <th>Leave Type</th>
      <th>Date From</th>
      <th>Date To</th>
      <th>Days</th>
      <th>Reason</th>
      <th>Responsible PIN</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```